# Task/Action-api for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, action

Is there any existing api/code for handling and chaining long-running "async" javascript functions?

First of all I don't think there are any such thing as an asynch function in js right? I guess the only asynch api is the http-request that jQuery uses or am I wrong?

Anyway, when using jQuery to first for instance ping a server, then login, then load a bunch of items etc, it's not very pretty to wrap these functions in each others completed-handler if you know what I mean.

What I have done now is to define a Task-class with some kind of linked-list capabilities, with a task.next-property etc. When I chain these and execute task.run on the first, I have designed it so that each task is run and when its completed-handler is called it runs the task.next task etc.

This works fine but I'm wondering is there is any existing more complete apis for this allready out there I should use?

Maybee with support for cancellation, progress, exception-aggregation etc?

Maybee there are plans for similar async/wait tasks as there are in C# now, but in js?

Comment: Have you done any research in this area? Have you seen [jquery defered](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) or [q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) or [taks.js](http://taskjs.org/)? There is even a [spec](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A)...

Comment: No I asked you ;) Sorry, I searched but was probably too tired too see.

Answer (score 0):

If you are targetting the browser, you can use setTimeout.. and break up your code into functions, with each iteraction taking one off the stack/queue, and doing that part.. there are also web workers...

If you are doing server-side JS (such as NodeJS), then there are libraries to make async tasks easier to manage.  In the browser it takes work...  You'll essentially want to create a bundle of tasks, and work them..

```
function processBundle(tasks, callback) {
  var hnd = setTimeout(doWork, 20);

  function doWork() {
    var item = tasks.shift();
    item();
    return (
      tasks.length 
        ? setTimeout(doWork, 20)
        : callback()
    );
  }
}

//using it...
var items = [];
items.push(simpleFunction1);
...
items.push(simpleFunctionN);
processBundle(items, function(){
  alert("done!");
});
```